# "legal" HTML Table with multiple title rows with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

I am trying to show a table for a 4 level data collection. Basicly something like this :

```
var data = [
    {
        group_id: 1,
        group_name: 'group1',
        subgroups: [
            {
                subgroup_id: 1,
                subgroup_name: 'subgroup1',
                elements : [
                    {
                        element_id: 1,
                        element_name: 'element1',
                        element_members: [
                            {
                                name: 'aaaa',
                                score: 150,
                                bonus: 32
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'bbbb',
                                score: 75,
                                bonus: 33
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        element_id: 2,
                        element_name: 'element2',
                        element_members: [
                            {
                                name: 'cccc',
                                score: 780,
                                bonus: 71
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'dddd',
                                score: 900,
                                bonus: 311
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                subgroup_id: 2,
                subgroup_name: 'subgroup2',
                elements: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        group_id: 2,
        group_name: 'group2',
        subgroups: []
    }
];
```

My big concern is to keep it "legal" HTML.

So I am currently iterating trough `groups` using a big `<div class="group" ng-repeat="group in data">` Inside each div I have tables like so :

`<table class="subgroup" ng-repeat="subgroup in group.subgroups">`

With one `thead` containing the column names : "subgroup name, element_name, total_scores, total_bonuses" then a ng-repeating tbody like so :

`<tbody ng-repeat="element in subgroup.elements">`

then again because I want to show the element totals inside each row and if clicked; the details for each element, So I have :

`<tr ng-click="element.expanded = !element.expanded">`

with the data inside it then a

```
<tr ng-if="typo.expanded">
    <td colspan="4">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Member name</th>
                    <th>Member score</th>
                    <th>Member bonus</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="member in element.element_members">
                    <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ member.score }}</td>
                    <td>{{ member.bonus }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Voila. All of this is working perfectly but I have one issue : I would like the column widths for each outer table (the one with total_scores, total_bonuses,...) to be aligned with one another but since they are different tables, it will adjust according to the size of the text. Also I want to keep this behaviour (adjusting to the size of the text) and not force a width for each column.

One solution that works but is not legal HTML is to use only one table for listing every subgroup and have a clandestine tag between `<table>` and `<thead>` and the following `<tbody>`s so that I could iterate trough subgroups inside the same table with the same columns but with multiple `<thead>`s for changing the first column name and repeating the other columns.

So what are my legit HTML options if there are any ?

## EDIT: Added a plnkr

[Here is a link to a plnkr illustrating my problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMrMl95yd5TQs60Jz5vu?p=preview) : the 2 tables (one for each subgroup) under one group title don't have the same column sizes and I wish I could make them fit into one table (so there would be one table per group instead) so that at least inside the same group, the subgroups are shown with the same column sizes.

Comment: Have you considered bootstrap or other CSS libraries for tables that does not use HTML element `table` ? Or just CSS grids like bootstrap grid system ? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I am currently using bootstrap and its table class. Using the grid system would only solve my problem if I decide for arbitrary widths for each column in advance which I can already do but I wish I don't have to because the data inside the table can be very changing in terms of length, I want the default behaviour of tables (`table-layout: auto`) to take care of sizing my columns depending on their content

Comment: Would adding a separate totals <tr> after ` <tr ng-repeat="member in element.element_members">`  work ?

Comment: Can you post the html reproducing the problem i.e. with the totals ? Or perhaps a plnkr

Comment: I don't have any problem with the totals. I just need the tables to have the same width, possibly by fitting all the data inside one table but how do I achieve that and still keep it W3C compliant ?

Comment: I have just added a plnkr link illustrating my problem to the question

Comment: Here http://plnkr.co/edit/rwMIFrLnZclF7XU74UrW?p=preview I have solved used separate tbody and $last. This aligns with the last group. However you have an intrinsic problem of alignment between two groups. What I am saying the problem is not confined to just Group totals. I suggest you create only one table even for every group since your group headings are going to be same.

Comment: Thank you, Alignment is not necessary between two groups so it's gonna be fine. However In your plnkr, only the first group has aligned subgroups, the second group in which one of the elements has a long title doesn't have the same alignment in its subgroups.

Comment: Actually @bhantol only the two last tables have aligned columns

Comment: Try the plnkr in the answer - it does have a different look and feel and a different approach to summing and totaling. But there is not going to be a good elegant option I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the column widths for each outer table (the one with total_scores, total_bonuses,...) to be aligned with one another but since they are different tables, it will adjust according to the size of the text.

Since they are multiple tables stacked over each other each table will align its columns based on its contents without any regard to other tables as expected.

> clandestine tag between  and  
>   multiple s

Both the above will leave it illegal as you pointed out.

**I believe following the main question:-**

> So what are my legit HTML options if there are any ?

There are no good (not ugly) alternative using `<table>` when you have a nesting that goes several levels deep AND items/groups of arbitrary length.

Here is the main reasons why:

- `<table>` can have only 1 `<thead>` and only 1 `tfoot` but the nester groups in your example goes several level deep `groups->subGroups->elements->members` and we want certain columns to align.
- Any elements like ng-switch or  to use for ng-repeaters are going to leave the HTML invalid.
- You want to display totals at group levels, sub group levels, element levels but only 1 `thead` is allowed AND the only element allowed under `<tbody>` is `<tr>` which will get taken by ng-repeaters.
- table nesting is not an option because then each table will decide how to align itself.

So by design any table with single thead allows nesting of at most up to 3 levels - one level for thead taken by column header, another level for multiple tbody and third level (leaf level) for multiple tr in them.

**Other ugly table option**

If you are willing to compromise on some of the look and feel you can [try this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXsZYFILmOP5JCOJNUXt?p=preview). Here we have flattened and injected total and parent elements. I do not recommend this and as per the comments I would suggest using  a less layout or other alternative beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Great ! That's a good idea flattening the table and adding the `level` property for use inside the `td`'s `ng-if`s. I will try to use this idea and adapt it to my case